# Indentifier smd sot23-6 mark as CASW

Tags: components

Can somebody indentifier this part?
It is mark as CASW 
[image]

Comment: Your image is broken...

Comment: I can see the image fine. It looks like there is a reference designator that starts with 'U'. What board are these parts on, and can you add one more picture zoomed out a little more?

Comment: I don't know of well-updated database of all SMD codes. The codes are stated inside the datasheet - but which datasheet? A chicken-and-egg problem. So it usually requires knowing the part's function, and knowing more about the circuit. To what other parts is this part connected? Can you reverse-engineer this section of the device? Do you recognize a ground and power-supply connections going certain pins? If so, it is more likely an IC, not diodes or transistors. Then, look at resistors or capacitiors that are connected around it. Is there a feedback network? If so, maybe it is an opamp?

Comment: These are on a electronic load.    It is the input for Volrage and current..

Comment: MCP3421AOT maybe. Although i only googled its picture

Comment: [Was there something wrong with the answer you got on this other site?](https://www.circuitsonline.net/forum/view/134310)

Comment: Mabye youre rigjht.  But egen i google it is notCASW but CATA or CA9D  so is the last 2 dont mather??

Comment: It appears from the picture that the reference designator begins with 'U.' This suggests that these are IC's, not transistors. I cannot understand the full answer in the website linked by @JRE, but it appears that the proposed answer does not really fit, because there are no vertical letters or numbers corresponding to the YY marking in the datasheet.

Comment: MCP3421AOT answer is plausible if the package really is a SOT23-6. I can see why you would put an 18-bit differential ADC on the input of an electronic load. But to me, the  package looks a bit too small to be a SOT23. Anyway, per datasheet, the marking on that part is CANN where NN is an alphanumeric code. Maybe the alphanumeric code is SW on these two parts.

Comment: Yes i think that it is right, i will order this one:  MCP3421A0T.  Thanks everyone for helping me!

Comment: If it works, please come back and answer your own question, adding the make and model of electronic load. Maybe it will help someone else down the road some day.

Comment: Yes it worked again both replace with MCP3421A0T.  Thanks everyone for helping me!!

Comment: It is a pcb with components from china. And it has no name only a 150Watt electronic load  10A max and 60V max.  You can buy it on ebay.